# Failing first name and last name regex test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, unit-testing

I am having quite a weird error in my rails' unit test.
I have the following test which fails for some reason:

```
should_not allow_value('@!>::<>').for(:first_name)
```

and the following validation in my model:

```
validates_format_of :first_name, :last_name, with: (/[\w]*/), allow_blank: true
```

Any ideas as to why the test fails?

**PS:** Error seems to go away when I change the `*` to a `+` in the regex...But why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/[\w]*/` matches **zero** or more word characters in the input. Since there are no word characters in your test string, it happily validates it. `/[\w]+/` needs at least one word character to have a match, and that's why it works with your test string.

I think you should use `/^[\w]*$/` to specify that from the start of your string to the end, you only want word characters (special characters `^` and `$` match the start and the end of input, respectively, in a regex). Note that this allows a blank input.

Comment: Yes..I just read it on regular-expressions.info as you posted. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You should actually use `\A` and `\z`, not `^` and `$`.  The former are start and end of **input**, while the latter are start and end of **line**, so that for example the name `"Bob\nDole"` will happily match `^\w+$` but won't match `\A\w+\z`.